# Convert RTP to RTSP in Jetson Nano

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano, ffserver

How Do I convert the RTP (provided by jetson.utils.videoOutput(“rtp://@:1234”)) to RTSP so that the same can ve streamed and be viewed over network.

I tried with FFserver as well as Streamer, but don't have much of an expertise in those.

Answer (score 0):

The dev branch of jetson-inference/jetson-utils has native support for RTSP output. See:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/convert-rtp-to-rtsp/239731/3